# Struggling with jQuery Toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, unbind

I am working on a band blurb page, example [here.](http://bigwavedesign.co.uk/openswimmer/band.php)

The idea is to click on a photo which will display the band member blurb on the left, overlaying the overall band description.

My issue with the current code is that using toggle to display the alternative individual blurbs means that when you click between the different members, sometimes the toggle state resets and it seems like nothing is happening. Each time you click a photo, that persons bio should display. Only when you click the same one twice, or a 'return to band bio' button (not yet on the page) should the main bio display.

My current code is below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('#gotoben').toggle(function() {
    $('li.gotoben').fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $("#dan").hide();
    $("#ben").show();
    $('li.gotoben').siblings().fadeTo("slow", 0.3);
},
  function () {
    $('li.gotoben').fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $('li.gotoben').siblings().fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $("#ben, #dan").hide();
}); 

$('#gotodan').toggle(function() {
    $('li.gotodan').fadeTo("slow", 1);      
    $("#ben").hide();
    $("#dan").show();
    $('li.gotodan').siblings().fadeTo("slow", 0.3);
},
  function () {
    $('li.gotodan').fadeTo("slow", 1);  
    $('li.gotodan').siblings().fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $("#dan, #ben").hide();
}); 

});
```

I have tried using the .click function but also cannot make everything work 100% smoothly.

Can anyone help me make this work?

**EDIT - WORKING CODE**

The only thing added here to patricks code is the inclusion of the jQuery `stop` function.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.bigLeft div:gt(0)').hide();

    $('ol.band li').click(function() {
        var $th = $(this);

            // Hide the current profiles
        $(".bigLeft").children().hide();

        if( $th.hasClass('selected') ) {
            $th.stop(true, false).siblings().fadeTo("slow", 1);
            $th.removeClass('selected');
            $('#theBand').show(); // <-- change the ID to the default
        } else {
            $th.addClass('selected');

              // Grab the ID of the one that was clicked
            var id = $th.attr('id');

              // Fade in the current, and fade the siblings
            $th.stop(true, false).fadeTo("slow", 1)
                   .siblings().removeClass('selected').stop(true, false).fadeTo("slow", 0.3);

              // Show the clicked profile by concatenating the ID clicked with '_profile'
            $("#" + id + "_profile").show();
        }
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would tend to take a little different approach.

Give each `li` under `ol.bind` the ID `#ben`, `#dan`, etc.

Then give each profile a similar ID `#ben_profile`, `#dan_profile`, etc.

Then use that consistency to your advantage:

```
$('ol.band li').click(function() {
    var $th = $(this);

        // Hide the current profiles
    $(".bigLeft").children().hide();

    if( $th.hasClass('selected') ) {
        $th.siblings().fadeTo("slow", 1);
        $th.removeClass('selected');
        $('#defaultProfile').show(); // <-- change the ID to the default
    } else {
        $th.addClass('selected');

          // Grab the ID of the one that was clicked
        var id = $th.attr('id');

          // Fade in the current, and fade the siblings
        $th.fadeTo("slow", 1)
               .siblings().removeClass('selected').fadeTo("slow", 0.3);

          // Show the clicked profile by concatenating the ID clicked with '_profile'
        $("#" + id + "_profile").show();
    }
});
```

**You can try it out here:** http://jsfiddle.net/kDqsT/

Comment: That works great except for if you click the selected profile again it does not return to the 'Band' bio. That was the main reason for using 'toggle' so you could return to the start so to speak.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: @DanC - That's alright. I added those later. I just updated. Untested, but I think it will work. Let me know. :o)

Comment: @patrick scrap last comment - that works just fine! Many thanks for your help! Now I can get back to watching the World Cup and not fretting over this minor design detail. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with the click function.

```
var current_loc = '';
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#gotoben').click(function() {
        if(current_loc != 'ben'){
            current_loc = 'ben';
            $('li.gotoben').fadeTo("slow", 1);
            $("#dan").hide();
            $("#ben").show();
            $('li.gotoben').siblings().fadeTo("slow", 0.3);
        }else{
            current_loc = '';
            $('li.gotoben').fadeTo("slow", 1);
            $('li.gotoben').siblings().fadeTo("slow", 1);
            $("#ben, #dan").hide();
        }
    }); 

    $('#gotodan').click(function() {
        if(current_loc != 'dan'){
            current_loc = 'dan';
            $('li.gotodan').fadeTo("slow", 1);      
            $("#ben").hide();
            $("#dan").show();
            $('li.gotodan').siblings().fadeTo("slow", 0.3);
        }else{
            current_loc = '';
            $('li.gotodan').fadeTo("slow", 1);  
            $('li.gotodan').siblings().fadeTo("slow", 1);
            $("#dan, #ben").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

I'm sure there are any number of better ways than this.

Comment: Can't seem to get that to work but many thanks for the suggestion! I'll have a play and see what happens!